# How Object class variables created?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, oop, object, actionscript

I have one question based on `Object` class 
In some Object oriented programming language `Object` class variables are used to store values and added to `ArrayList, ArrayCollection, etc..,` 
actionscript example:

```
var obj:Object = new Object();
obj.firstName = 'stack';
obj.lastName = 'overflow';
```

How `firstName` and `lastName` variables created? 
Why `firstName and lastName` doesnot throw errors because inside `Object` class firstName and lastName variables not available.

Comment: They created on the fly and added to that object.

Comment: Is this about Java, or about JavaScript? `var` says JavaScript; `ArrayList` is Java. Java != JavaScript.

Comment: This is actionscript example not java.

Comment: Can you change the tags to reflect whether the answer should be about `[java]` or `[actionscript]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ActionScript these are called "Dynamic" Classes and Object is a base class that is dynamic by default.

> A dynamic class defines an object that can be altered at run time by
>   adding or changing properties and methods. A class that is not
>   dynamic, such as the String class, is a sealed class. You cannot add
>   properties or methods to a sealed class at run time.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f89.html

As a comparison, in C# this would be like an "ExpandoObject" Class.

> Represents an object whose members can be dynamically added and
>   removed at run time.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

in your code `Object` class is build in class when you create an object of class `Object`:

```
 obj:Object = new Object();
```

you call the constructor of this Class which has its own variables and methods 
the variables may be `public` or `private`
in your example the variables `firstName,lastName` is public so you can call them directly by dot `.` and you can change their values while if they are `private` you should use methods to change and get their values

so all the variables and methods of class is encapsulated in it when you create object of this class they will be created directly

Comment: I don't see a relation the the question(s) in this answer